# $V$-regular lines, finite morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a linear space over $k$ of dimension $n$. Consider an affine
algebraic variety $X$ and $x$ a finite morphism of algebraic varieties $v : X \to V$.

We say that a line $l \subset V$ (i.e. a point $l$ in $P(V)$) is regular if the composition morphism 
$v' = pr * v : X \to V/l$ is finite.

Let us denote by $R$ the subset $R = R_v \subset P(V)$ of v-regular lines.

Suppose we know that $\dim X < n$. Show that the subset $R$ is dense in
$P(V)$.

Show that the subset $R$ is open in $P(V)$.